# Обработчик событий не реагирует на событие другого компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Только начал изучать vue.js, и появилась проблема - почему-то не срабатывает обработчик событий `showModal` компонента `MyModal`, когда событие возникает в компоненте `MyButton`.

Глобальный объект `Vue` с компонентами:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
// Сторонний компонент модальных окон
Vue.use(require('vue-js-modal').default);

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
components: {
    'my-button': require('./components/MyButton'),
    'my-modal': require('./components/MyModal'),
}
```

});

Компонент `MyButton`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button v-on:click="notify">Show modal</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            notify() {
                console.log('click on button');
                this.$emit('clickShowModal');
            },
        }
    };
</script>
```

Компонент `MyModal`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <modal name="hello-world-modal">
            hello, world!
        </modal>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            showModal() {
                // Этот метод НЕ вызывается из компонента MyButton
                console.log('show modal');
                this.$modal.show('hello-world-modal');
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Рендринг компонентов:

```
<my-button></my-button>
<my-modal @clickShowModal="showModal()"></my-modal>
```

Что не так? ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь у вас обработчик на кнопке должен стоять, а не в модальном окне:

```
<my-button @clickShowModal="$refs.modal.showModal()"></my-button>
<my-modal ref="modal"></my-modal>
```

Comment: Тогда он не сможет найти метод showModal т.к. этот метод находится в другом компоненте.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, это не всегда хорошая практика, но можно использовать ref для обращения к методам.